# what is the regular expression that matches from one substring to a second one, without another one in between?

Tags: python, regex

I want to match from a substring `foo` to a substring `bar`, but without a substring `baz` occuring in between.  (Python is preferred, so negative/positive lookahead is fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below regex which uses negative lookahead,

```
foo(?:(?!baz).)*bar
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nG1gU7/25)

`(?:(?!baz).)*` tells the regex engine to match any character zero or more times but not the string `buz`.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """fooblahblahbar
... fooblahbazbar"""
>>> m = re.findall(r'foo(?:(?!baz).)*bar', s, re.M)
>>> m
['fooblahblahbar']
```

Comment: Yes I know.  I am good enough to understand your brilliant answer Sir :)  I am just not good enough to come up with it myself.  :)

Answer (score 1):

An other way *(less handy, but more efficient, in particular with long strings)*:

```
bear(?=((?:[^cd]+|c+(?!at)|d+(?!og))*))\1bar
```

This pattern emulate a feature that is not available in python: [the atomic group](http://regular-expressions.com/atomic.html)

The same pattern with an atomic group is: `bear(?>[^cd]+|c+(?!at)|d+(?!og))*dog`

The trick to emulate this feature is to use the fact that a lookahead assertion is atomic (you can't remove characters once the closing parenthesis is reached). If you put a capture group inside and you use a backreference after, you obtain an atomic group:

```
(?>expression)    <=>    (?=(expression))\1
```

Where `\1` is the backreference.

**Limitations of this approach:**

If the target string contains an high density of first characters ("d" and "c" in the example), this will slow down the regex engine work, since it has more tests to do *(you loose the advantage that gives the first greedy quantifier `[^cd]+`)*

Comment: Yes, pardon me, but of course I used foo , bar, baz merely as placeholders.  These are long strings and bear no particular relationship to each other.

Comment: Actually, this does not work for me, does not match anything.

Comment: >>> re.search("bear(?=([^cd]+|c+(?!at)|d+(?!og))*)\1dog", "bear dog")  (returns nothing)

Comment: @MarkGaleck: Sorry, I have forgotten a group: `bear(?=((?:[^cd]+|c+(?!at)|d+(?!og))*))\1dog`

Comment: @MarkGaleck: when you use a backslash inside a pattern, you must enclose it in a raw string: `re.search(r'bear(?=((?:[^cd]+|c+(?!at)|d+(?!og))*))\1dog', "bear dog")` or you must escape it: `re.search('bear(?=((?:[^cd]+|c+(?!at)|d+(?!og))*))\\1dog', "bear dog")`